# batch: access another variable by the value of one variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, scope

I do apologize if the title is confusing. here is my batch script:

```
set var=1
set ss=var rem // ss is mean to be string
call :func %ss%
goto :eof

:func
    rem // I want to access to value 1 by using %1, which is ss
```

Is there any way to do it? I will be grateful if you offer some help ^v^

Comment: `echo !%1!` with Delayed Expansion Enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set var=1
set ss=var rem // ss is mean to be string
call :func %ss%
goto :eof

:func
    REM I want to access to value 1 by using %1, which is ss
    set a=%1
    REM will output '1'
    echo !%a%!
```

Evaluation: `!%a%! => !var! => 1`

Comment: No need to assign the argument to an environmental variable.  All you need is `!%1!`